# Given a pathname and a symlink to a directory in the pathname, is there a command which can return an equivalent pathname making use of the symlink?

Tags: files, filenames, symlink

Sometimes I have a long pathname, and want to shorten it by some precreated symlink to a directory in the pathname. Specifically, given a   pathname `/path/to/file`, and a symbolic link `/symlink` to a   directory `/path/to`  in the pathname, is there a command which can return an equivalent pathname `/symlink/file`, to makes use of the symlink?

(optional, my focus is on the above for now) Furthermore, given a   pathname, and a directory of symbolic links to  directories, is there a command which can find out  if there is any symlink to "a directory appearing in the pathname", and if yes, return an equivalent pathname using the symlink?

Thanks.

Comment: Given multiple possible choices, what should this utility do? Optimize for shortest length? Deepest link / fewest directories?

Comment: (IMHO, the first question could be independent of the 2nd).

Comment: To canonicalize symlinks you would use `readlink`. Have a look at its options `-f`, `-e`, `-m`.

Comment: @Freddy What is "canonicalize symlinks "?

Comment: @Tim I would say it's "the shortest absolute path" as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100299/whats-a-canonical-path/12100378#12100378

Comment: Are you trying to convert "/path/to/file" into "/symlink/file" ?  If so... "no, there is no such command".  Given a number of assumptions you could use a `sed` statement, but there's no general purpose command.

Comment: Very unclear. For the first part, based on what rule? Second part, is "in the path name" the qualifier of "symlink" or "directory"?

Comment: It seems like you are searching for a symlink to a specific directory, which is almost impossible, since that needs to search the whole VFS tree.

Comment: `stat` shows you if your path is a symbolic link or not and `stat -L` dereferences links.

Comment: Which leads to my suspicion that this is X-Y. Since people usually parse symlink to canonical path, not the other way around.

Comment: What o you mean by "X-Y"? @炸